# UIScrollView doesn't work after App Store update

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, itunes

I have submitted an update of my application to `iTunes` which I got it approved today. Lately I have downloaded it on my device from `iTunes` to check and I found one functionality is not working as expected.

**Problem:**

I have a `UIScrollView` in my app and has horizontal scrolling. After the update I am not able to scroll it. I restarted the app and then it starts scrolling but scrolling infinite horizontally. I know this sounds stupid.

Immediately I opened my project code and ran it on device to check the issue using development provisioning profile but it is working perfectly over there. 
Can any one suggest me what can be the issue? Or how can I debug that what went wrong when I submitted the update to `iTunes`?

Comment: Those kinds of problems don't appear from nowhere. The version of iOS system the app was tested plays a big role here, I think.

Comment: Found this problem with all devices having ios5 and ios6.

Answer (score 0):

You give us very little to work with, but here are a couple of suggestions:

- Make sure you're looking at *exactly* the same code
- Make sure you're testing code built with *exactly* the same compiler settings. For example, usually when you're running from Xcode you'll compile in debug mode. Don't. Compile it in "release" mode (with all the optimisations switched on)
- Don't worry about provisioning profiles; they won't be the problem

If it's affecting all iOS 5 and 6 devices, though, I do wonder how you were testing it? And how fundamental is the scrolling to your app? It did, after all, pass Apple's testing. Maybe it's only happening on your devices because it has some "junk" left over from your previous testing?

Comment: Thanks for reply Stephen, still I am not able to find out the reason for app's behavior. For first two points you mention - I have created a `tag` on `git` for this version from where I am taking the code. I am not sure but re-submitting to iTunes will work? Just a wild guess.

Comment: If you don't change anything, why would resubmitting it make any difference?

Comment: yes you've got the point.. I'd better be start digging the code with every possible way to find out the issue. I don't have enough rep. to upvote you but when I have it I'll surely upvote you.. Thanks for your help. :)